# object-fit fallback solution? (AngularJS&ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I've got an interesting compatability issue. Of course, object-fit: cover will not work on MS Edge and IE, so I've been trying to find a workaround for it. However, I can't seem to access an image created using ng-repeat via javascript.

I want to be able to edit the image styles from the controller, but querySelector('img') always returns null.

Heres the HTML:

```
<div class="js-image" id="danCarousel" style="height: 600px; width: 100%; background-color: grey;">
<!-- carousel image -->
<img ng-show="loaded" class="cimg {{fadeAnimation}}" ng-repeat="slide in slides" 
    ng-if="isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.src}}" style="position: absolute;
     height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover; float: left; "/>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
danApp.controller('indexController', function($scope, $document, $timeout, QueueService) {
$scope.state='index';

if('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
    console.log("This browser does not support object-fit");

    //get the carousel image container
    var carouselImages = document.getElementsByClassName('js-image');

    for(var i=0; i < carouselImages.length; i++) {

        console.log(i);
        //get the image source url
        var imageSrc = carouselImages[i].querySelector('img').getAttribute("ng-src");
        console.log(carouselImages[i].querySelector('img'));

        //hide the image
        carouselImages[i].querySelector('img').style.display = "none";

        //add background-size: cover
        carouselImages[i].style.backgroundSize = 'cover';

        //add in the background image src here
        carouselImages[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageSrc + ')';

        //Add background-position: center center
        carouselImages[i].style.backgroundPosition = 'center center';
    }

    console.log("Compatability settings added.");
}
else {
    console.log('This browser supports object-fit');
}
```

Anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class and either call a function in your controller to return the appropriate class name or add a class property to slide and reference it via ng-class.

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting querySelector returns null :(

Comment: You should not need to use the querySelector if you're using ng-class. Pass the slide object into your function and reference the image location from slide.src.